# SP16 On-Premise - SPFx web parts or Classic web Parts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, spfx, spfx-webparts

My company has need to migrate web parts from SP07 to SP16 On-Premise.

It is clear that all the logic from the old web parts will be written from the beginning. My question is what decision we choose to create webpages because they will not be in the cloud.

> SPFx Webpart or Old classic visual web parts for SharePoint
>   On-Premise infrasctructure? What can we do based on such an
>   architecture using the maximum of server capabilities?

Comment: SPFX is not supported yet in SP2016 on-presime

Comment: I know :) It is not yet available for 2016 On Premises. It will be available via Feature Packs later this year for On Prem

Comment: I'm getting ready to know whether to wait for On-Premise...

Comment: Don't ask multiple question under a single question.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222782/sp16-migrate-webparts-from-sp07?noredirect=1#comment239416_222782

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPFX web is not supported yet in SP2016 on-primise. It will be available via Feature Pack.

https://rencore.com/blog/sharepoint-framework-webinar-qa-follow-part-1-sharepoint-framework

> Currently SharePoint Framework is available in SharePoint Online only.
>   In the future it will be also available for SharePoint 2016
>   on-premises. At this moment there are no plans in making it available
>   to previous versions of SharePoint.

So, for the time being, you have to use visual web part or client side development.

Comment: I know for this.  When it's available, I want to know what to use and whether it's worth waiting for it

Comment: MSFT did not declare any date of its availability. If it is urgent for your client, then go with visual web part. Otherwise, you can wait.

Comment: it's a different question. You should ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Or RE define your whole strategy: Think SharePoint is but another database

You then built an API to tier the SharePoint data

Then can built any SPA on top.